# Python: Readline returns error after 10 lines

Tags: python, file-io, io, readline

I'm trying to use readline on file in a for loop. The problem is that I start getting I/O errors. It seems that I get I/O error after 10 readlines.

Here is my function:

```
def getAll():
with open("nodes2.txt", "r+") as f:
    for i in range(0, 200):
        print "**%s**"%(i)
        try:
            file = f.readline()
            file = file[:-1]
            # print "*%s*" % (file)
            entities = getAllPagesEntities(file)
            # print entities
            for en in entities:
                try:
                    dict = getFirmAttributes(en)
                    printToFile(dict)
                except Exception,e:
                    with open("log_getFirmAttributes.txt","a") as f:
                        f.write(str(e))
                        f.write("\n")
        except Exception,e:
            with open("log_readFile.txt","a") as f:
                f.write(str(e))
                f.write("\n")
```

Here is a printed catched exception:

```
I/O operation on closed file
```

I think that this problem can't be caused by another used functions so I don't attach them here.  I thought that it is caused by the file used but when I try to readline 200 and print them, everything works perfect.

```
with open("nodes2.txt", "r+") as f:
    for i in range(0, 200):
        print f.readline()
```

Have you any idea what could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the entire stack trace for the error? You should be able to print out that information too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following lines in the `except` block overwrites `f` causing open file to be closed.

```
with open("log_readFile.txt","a") as f:
    f.write(str(e))
    f.write("\n")
```

Change the name `f` for the file for appending to another name will solve the problem:

```
with open("log_readFile.txt", "a") as logf:
    logf.write(str(e))
    logf.write("\n")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't notice that for two hours.